# Do two column equivalent systems share the same solution set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

We know that if two system of linear equations are row equivalent then they share the same solution set,but can we say the same for column equivalence as well?i.e.given a system $Ax=b$and another system $Cx=d$ such that $[A|b]$and $[C|d]$are column equivalent,can we conclude that they have the same solution set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $[A|\lambda b]$ is column equivalent to $[A|b]$ for any nonzero scalar $\lambda.$  This should be apparent that it breaks solution sets.

For a simple [if somewhat degenerate] example, assuming $A = b = 1$ (i.e. $A, x, b \in \mathbb{R}$) gives $x = 1,$ but this is column equivalent to $x = 2$ by choosing $\lambda = 2.$

---

If you want, you can look at every "elementary column operation" to answer this question more generally.  It should be apparent that none of them maintains all solution sets.

Comment: But is consistency preserved under column operation?

Comment: I am sure about the operations $C_{ij}$ and $C_{j}(c)$

Comment: "Swapping two columns" shows that $0x = 1$ is column-equivalent to $1x = 0,$ so no.

Comment: Oh I got it....